# Node js - Get certificate thumbprint using node-forge as cross platform application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using node-forge distribution from below link

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge-dist/blob/master/dist/forge.min.js

How to get Certificate thumbprint in my application using node-forge as cross platform application. My application is connection to some domain like www.anydomain.com every time it makes ajax call to get the data from the services. I want to read certificate thumbprint to apply some logic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSy5m.png)

Please help if anybody have the solution.

Answer (score 8):

It's not really straightforward, but (if your certificate is `cert` variable):

```js
const md = forge.md.sha1.create();
md.update(forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert)).getBytes());
const hex = md.digest().toHex();
```